# Can someone break this sed command down for me?

Tags: sed

I found this magical command on the unix forum to move the last line of a file to the beginning of the file. I use sed quite a bit but not to this extent. Can someone explain each part to me?

```
sed '1h;1d;$!H;$!d;G' infile
```

Comment: start here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: `man sed` or `info sed` are good starting point to unravel the magic. If after reading the help you still cannot understand what this command does, ask aagin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it uses exotic commands.

- 1h: put first line in the "hold" space (sed has 2 spaces: 1 hold space to keep data and the pattern space: actual processed line)
- 1d: delete first line
- $!H: append all lines BUT the last one (and the first one since d command skips to the next line) into the "hold" space
- $!d: delete (do not print) all lines except the last one
- G: Append a newline to the contents of the pattern space (this is the last line, the only one able to reach that part of the script), and then append the contents of the hold space to that of the pattern space, pattern space which is printed right away. Swap done.

*Opinion based comment*: I must admit I would never have thought of doing that using `sed`, and I would have had to make a test to convince me of what this command was doing... in `awk`, it is much much easier to do that.
 But `sed` has a special place in my heart with it's cryptic commands. I wonder if there are some `sed` candidates to CodeGolf :)

- reference manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html
- some exotic things you can do with sed (my best 1999 read): http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/do_it_with_sed.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same command in a more procedural-looking pseudocode:

```python
for line in infile:
    # Always do this: Copy the current line to the pattern
    pattern = line

    # Process the script
    if first line:
        hold = pattern                 # 1h
        pattern = ""; continue         # 1d
    elif not last line:
        hold = hold + "\n" + pattern   # $!H
        pattern = ""; continue         # $!d
    pattern = pattern + "\n" + hold    # G

    # Always do this after the script is completed.
    # Due to the continue statements above, this
    # isn't always reached, and in this case
    # is only reached for the last line.
    print pattern
```

- `d` clears the pattern space and continues to the next input line without executing the rest of the script.
- `h` copies the pattern space to the hold space.
- `H` appends a newline to the hold space, then appends the pattern space to the hold space.
- `G` is like `H`, but in the other direction; it copies the hold space to the pattern space.

The overall affect on a file with N lines is to build up a copy of lines 1 through N-1 in the hold space. When the pattern holds line N, append the hold space to the pattern space and print the pattern space to standard output.